# Closing Documents During Runtime

Tags: python, command-line, perforce, p4v

I am using Python to create a script to run perforce commands in command prompt. One of the commands opens a file. I want to write to the bottom of the file, then save the file, and then close the file after. I do not know what the file will be named it is different every time and the command is run 5 or more times for each time I run the program. The Command is:
    `os.system('p4 user -f ' + name)`

Comment: So you just want to write plain text to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're actually trying to do is modify a Perforce user spec.  This is super easy.  If you use P4Python you have a nice API to the spec objects:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.save_spectype

and can do things like:

```
user = p4.get_user(name)
# do things
p4.save_user(user)
```

If you want to script without P4Python, the basic command line has much better options than trying to script around the editor.  For example:

```
p4 --field Reviews+=//depot/whatever/... user -o NAME | p4 user -i -f
```

will add `//depot/whatever/...` to the bottom of `NAME`'s `Reviews` field.

Or if you don't like the `--field` option you can parse and modify the spec yourself:

```
p4 user -o NAME | **REGEX MAGIC** | p4 user -i -f
```

---

If you really want to script a command like `p4 user` and not use a scripting API or the convenient `-o`/`-i`/ hooks that avoid having it invoke an editor with a temp file (in other words if you're a scripting masochist looking for a unique challenge), your best bet is to override `P4EDITOR` and have it point to a script that you've written.  Whatever executable is specified by `P4EDITOR` will get invoked with the temp file name; the modified spec will be uploaded (from the temp file) as soon as `P4EDITOR` exits.

Comment: The easier the better currently I'm reading the names from a text file and then creating the users that way using the command I showed above is there a way to use the command set the authentication to LDAP without opening the temp file? Or if the P4python is the best option how do I go about setting it up

Comment: Yup, either of the options I outlined above will work for creating users with whatever options you want!  Can't give good code samples in these tiny comment fields so feel free to post a new and more specific question if you'd like an answer more geared to what you're trying to do specifically.  :)